# jQuery Math.random: avoid repeating same item

Tags: javascript, jquery, random, fadein

I have this function which makes my divs "slide" randomly every 3 seconds:

```
$(function () {
  $('.fadein p:gt(0)').hide();
  setInterval(function () {
      var randomize = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * $('.fadein > p').length);
      $('.fadein > p').fadeOut();
      $('.fadein > :nth-child(' + randomize + ')').fadeIn();
  }, 3000);
});
```

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/775pR/1/). The problem is that sometimes the slides are the same (as the random number generated is the same twice in a row). Can you help me creating some variable to store the last number generated so when the function calls Math.random(), if that number equals the last number generated it calls it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check which `p` are visible before doing you random. Then, you should play within that stack to be sure you are not randoming the same image twice. This code does it :

```
$(function () {
    $('.fadein p:gt(0)').hide();
    setInterval(function () {
        var $p = $('.fadein > p').not(':visible') //Select only the hidden one
        var randomize = Math.floor(Math.random() * $p.length); //Use only those hidden, remove the 1 since we are now on a 0-based index
        $('.fadein > p').fadeOut();
        $p.eq(randomize).fadeIn(); //Use eq on the hidden p
    }, 3000);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/775pR/3/

Comment: Wow! Perfect! Just as last touch... how can I make also the first p random? I tried setting p:gt(-1) but doesn't quite work..

Comment: @DioCane with a single selector, you can't. But you can use that : http://jsfiddle.net/775pR/9/

Answer (score 1):

Try with this example if you want to use "all in one" selector:

```
$('.fadein > p' ).fadeOut();
$('.fadein > p:not(:visible):eq(' + Math.floor( Math.random() * ($('.fadein > p' ).length-1) ) + ')' ).fadeIn();
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Djwd9/)**